# Mysql innjer join with one to many duplicate records

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Suppose I've Below tables

**student** :

```
id  Name
-------------------
1   john
2   carlos
3   zoya
4   arab
5   amir
```

and,

**email** :

```
id      email   student_id
--------------------------
1   a@mail.com      1
2   b@mail.com      2
3   c@mail.com      2
4   d@mail.com      3
5   e@mail.com      4
```

and Using sql query to get student name along with emails,

```
SELECT student.name, email.eid FROM student 
INNER JOIN email 
ON student.id = email.student_id
```

and it will give below output,

```
Name        eid
-------------------
john    a@mail.com
carlos  b@mail.com
carlos  c@mail.com
zoya    d@mail.com
amir    e@mail.com
```

here the duplicate entry(not actually duplicate) for `carlos` returned,
but i want only single student list for example like this, ( either `b@gmail.com` or `c@gmail.com` doesn't matter).

```
Name        eid
-------------------
john    a@mail.com
carlos  b@mail.com
zoya    d@mail.com
amir    e@mail.com
```

I've not much experience in sql,

I've used `DISTINCT` but it wont works .. please help

Not :  I'm storing emails in different tables in case if there is need in future.

Comment: You can use `GROUP BY name`

Comment: Which one? Why b and not c

Comment: It's not a duplicate entry, the user carlos has two different emails.  You can GROUP BY if you dont want two carlos users.

Comment: If you want any email address for a student not specific to old/recent criteria just add group by student id

Comment: @Strawberry it can be any one `b` or `c` doesn't matters

Comment: If it doesn't matter, then that implies you have bigger problems with your data! It *should* matter!

Comment: @Strawberry No !!! It really doen't matter .. only one email id is more than enough .. there is no need other ..

Comment: @Strawberry i guess user is inserting email on update criteria too :) because if there is no need for more than one email then user should implement the update logic to update previous email instead to insert new one

Comment: Thanks commentators for suggesting `GROUP By` especially @MKhalidJunaid .. results are exactly as expected.

Comment: See my Updated answer ... why i'm getting sql error on query line 4 .. ??

Comment: @user3710243 - If you have a different error, you should ask a new question rather than hack up your old question, which makes the answers already given useless.

Comment: Be VERY careful with MYSQL's group by http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html  The results you're getting are how mysql works out of the box.  But this is not how other RDBMS support group by statements.

Comment: Question moved as new question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25493080/mysql-getting-error-with-inner-join-with-group-by-and-where-clause

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem, because some students have multiple emails and you are only looking for one.  If you don't care which one, then use `MIN()` or `MAX()`:

```
SELECT s.name, MIN(e.eid)
FROM student s INNER JOIN
     email e
     ON s.id = e.student_id
GROUP BY s.name;
```

If you do care which one, then you need to explain the logic for choosing amongst multiples.

Comment: Missing the `group by` ?  In MySQL I guess you can even omit the `min()` as it will grab a random value by default

Answer (score -2):

This should work

```
SELECT distinct student.name, email.eid FROM student 
INNER JOIN email 
ON student.id = email.student_id
```

Why you're storing emails in different table and then joining them, you can store them in students table itself, that makes design simpler and querying easier.

Comment: Distinct not works ... i'm storing emails in different tables in case if there is need in future ..