# Error for INNER JOIN with GROUP BY and WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I've got these tables

**student:**

```
id  Name
-------------------
1   john
2   carlos
3   zoya
4   arab
5   amir
```

and,

**email:**

```
id      email   student_id
--------------------------
1   a@mail.com      1
2   b@mail.com      2
3   c@mail.com      2
4   d@mail.com      3
5   e@mail.com      4
```

I'm using this query and it's getting `Using sql error on query line 4`,

```
SELECT * FROM student 
INNER JOIN email 
ON student.id = email.student_id 
GROUP BY student.id
WHERE student.id = 2
```

I don't have much experience in SQL.

Comment: And where is the `GROUP BY` clause?

Comment: sorry .. I've forget it .. Question is updated

Comment: @user3710243 put group by after where clause

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid Thanks man once again . but i doubt that i've heard once that `WHERE` clause should be put at last of the query .. .

Comment: @user3710243 you have to follow the syntax for your query as mentioned in [*`Docs`*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html)

Comment: Do you really need `GROUP BY`? Can a student have multiple entries in the `email` table? If so, are you OK with it picking one of them at random?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, `GROUP BY` always goes after the `WHERE` clause.
Secondly, if you are using the `GROUP BY` clause you should either use aggregate functions for the fields, that are not contained in it and still are present in the `SELECT` clause, or `GROUP BY` the whole pack of columns contained in the `SELECT`.

Comment: but as mentioned http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1392479/using-where-and-inner-join-in-mysql. i was using `WHERE` clause at last.

Comment: @user3710243 : It is not right, use link that  *M Khalid Junaid* has provided to check the correct order of the clauses.